# Start octave with GUI from cron

Tags: linux, cron, octave

I would like to use a cronjob to open octave with the force-gui option.

Writing

```
00 22 * * * octave --force-gui > ~/log 2>&1
```

doesn't start octave but gives the log message

```
octave: unrecognized option '--force-gui'

usage: octave [-HVdfhiqvx] [--debug] [--echo-commands] [--eval CODE]
     [--exec-path path] [--help] [--image-path path] [--info-file file]
     [--info-program prog] [--interactive] [--line-editing]
     [--no-history] [--no-init-file] [--no-init-path] [--no-line-editing]
     [--no-site-file] [--no-window-system] [-p path] [--path path]
     [--silent] [--traditional] [--verbose] [--version] [file]
```

When I enter

```
octave --force-gui
```

directly in the terminal, octave opens just fine.

I noticed that the same error as in the log file is produced when I enter

```
/usr/bin/octave --force-gui
```

into a terminal.

> **Question:** How can I start the octave GUI via Cron?

I am using Octave version 3.8.1 on Linux Mint 16.

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want to start the GUI from a cron job? I typically use the CLI version to batch process some logfiles/data and can't see no reason someone wants to start the GUI with cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have two different versions of Octave installed. One in `/usr/bin/octave` (an older version without the `--force-gui` option), and a new version that is in your path but not on the path when cron runs.

Type `which octave` to see where is the octave version you want to run and fix your paths. You may want to uninstall the old version of Octave too.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, my version 3.8.1 octave is in /usr/local/bin, whereas /usr/bin contains the older version 3.6.4. So the order in which these paths are searched is different for a command entered in the terminal and one executed via Cron?

Comment: @Eckhard depends on the user that runs the cronjob. It may not even have `/usr/local/bin` in the path.